# Postgresql + PostGIS: find record by geometry column

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE main.address_list
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  address_string text NOT NULL,
  address_position geometry(Point,4326)
  CONSTRAINT pk_address_list PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to find some record in this table using the `address_position` column:

```
select *
       , public.ST_Y(al.address_position) latitude
       , public.ST_X(al.address_position) longitude
from address_list al
where al.address_position = public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_MakePoint(56.187339 --longitude$n
                                                                  , 57.964295 --latitude$n
                                                                  ), 4326)
```

But I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator is not unique: public.geometry = public.geometry
LINE 5: where al.address_position = public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_Make...
                                  ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I get explicit type cast?

Comment: SELECT *, ST_Y(adress_position) AS latitude isn't working? Did you try anything else that's working?

Comment: Check this : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42970/how-to-get-coordinates-from-geometry-in-postgis and btw you should really post your "GIS related questions" on the dedicated stack gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare two `geometries` with the equals-to `=` operator. That is not supported; instead you should use some spatial relationship function. Probably the best thing is to use a minimal distance:

```
select *
       , public.ST_Y(al.address_position) latitude
       , public.ST_X(al.address_position) longitude
from address_list al
where public.ST_DWithin(al.address_position::geography
                      , public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_MakePoint(56.187339 --longitude$n
                                                            , 57.964295 --latitude$n
                                         ), 4326)::geography
                      , 1.); -- maximum separation of 1m
```

Alternatively, you can compare the latitude and longitude values for equality:

```
select *
       , public.ST_Y(al.address_position) latitude
       , public.ST_X(al.address_position) longitude
from address_list al
where public.ST_X(al.address_position) = 56.187339  --longitude$n
  and public.ST_Y(al.address_position) = 57.964295; --latitude$n
```

But you should keep in mind that comparing floating point values for equality is usually not a safe option due to the representation in binary form.

Comment: Thank you @Patrick for notice about not supported equals-to operator for two geometries. I think I could use some function to convert geometry to WKT and compare that values.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted geometry column to WKT (Well Known Text) and compare that values.

```
select *
       , public.ST_Y(al.address_position) latitude
       , public.ST_X(al.address_position) longitude
       , public.ST_AsText(al.address_position)
from address_list al
where public.ST_AsText(al.address_position) = public.ST_AsText(public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_MakePoint(56.187339 --longitude$n
                                                                                                     , 57.964295 --latitude$n
                                                                                                     ), 4326)
                                                               )
```

And added function index on column address_position

```
CREATE INDEX i_address_position_as_text
  ON address_list
  USING btree
  (public.ST_AsText(address_position));
```